# How to catch CORS error while loading external website in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, tracking

Loading external website in an iframe is getting blocked because of x-frame-options in response headers. I want to listen to the error from iframe and show some alert to the user. So is there any way to catch the exception/error while loading external content in an iframe??

Comment: I found this: [catch iframe CORS](https://code.sololearn.com/WDt89r2nBPo1/?ref=app)

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` errors are **not** CORS errors.